# Pythonで多重階層下の.pyファイルインポートするにはどうすればいいか

Tags: python

以下のようなディレクトリ構造があるとします。

```
testApp
  |__ main.py
  |__ dirA
        |__ __init__.py
        |__ test.py
        |__ dirB
              |__ __init__.py
              |__ test2.py
```

私は、それぞれのファイルに以下のようなコードを記述しました。

**main.py**

```
import dirA
dirA.dirB.test2.main_func()
```

**dirA/**init**.py**

```
from . import test
from * import dirB
```

**dirA/test.py**

```
def sample_func():
    print("sample func")

def main_func():
    sample_func()
```

**dirA/dirB/**init**.py**

```
from . import test2
```

**dirA/dirB/test2.py**

```
def sample_func2():
    print("sample func2")

def main_func2():
    sample_func()
```

しかし、これを実行すると以下のようなエラーが出ます。
エラー内容は以下の通りです。

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dirA
  File "C:\Users\username\Documents\hold\testApp\dirA\__init__.py", line 2
    from * import dirB
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

最上位のディレクトリ直下にあるファイル内で、importの記述を1つだけにして2階層下までのファイルをimportするにはどのような記述をすればできるのでしょうか？

もしくは、このような記述方法が望ましくない場合、**init**.py等を活用してスマートにimportするにはどういった記述をするのが適切なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import`文の書き方が間違っているためエラーが発生しています。
下記の書き方でimportの記述を1つだけにして2階層下の`test2`にアクセスできます。
(記述を省略したファイルには変更ありません)

**main.py**

```
import dirA
dirA.dirB.test2.sample_func2()
# sample func2
```

**dirA/**init**.py**

```
from .dirB import *
```

**dirA/dirB/**init**.py**

```
from . import test2
```

参考資料:

- [Pythonの相対インポートで上位ディレクトリ・サブディレクトリを指定](https://note.nkmk.me/python-relative-import/)